# A strange ghost line appearing in WPF near Label with WindowStyle="None"

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Here is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWindow.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

        <Label Content="Test label" />
</Window>
```

It produces the following image:

[image]

It seems to reproduce constantly with as long as the following parameters are set:

- ResizeMode = "NoResize"
- WindowStyle = "None"
- SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight"

I hoped it'd disappear if I set a border color for the window, however, it stays there even if I do that...

Anyone has an idea of how I can make this line disappear?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` to the window properties.

What I think you are seeing here is a sliver of the black behind the window background. You can see this black in full if you set the Background color to Transparent.